# Having problems with a google map administered through google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-react

The map loads but without any actual content. The sidebars to zoom etc load fine but no actual map. I've played around with syntax quite a bit but nothing that bears fruit. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is there a minor syntactical error that could be a quick fix? "lati" logs to the console just fine. I still consider myself a student of react.js so my apologies if this seems kind of amateur hour but I'd love any insight the community could provide. Thank you.

The variables to try to pass the props are about a 3rd attempt at getting this to run. I tried to pass the props directly and that was a no go to even render.

````
import MapCS from './Map';
import Weather from './Weather'
import {
  BrowserRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Stats from'./Stats'

//Game Component for Notre dame
class NotreDame extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
              <h2>Louisville vs Notre Dame @ Cardinal Stadium</h2>
              <Weather location="louisville" />
              <Stats />
              <MapCS lat="36.166479" lon="86.7712898"/>
          </div>
      </ BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default NotreDame;

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

//Map Styling
const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '500px'
};

// Map Component
class MapCS extends Component {
  render(props) {

    const lati = this.props.lat
    const long = this.props.lon
    console.log(lati)
    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={17}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: lati,
            lng: long
        }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "*redacted*"
})(MapCS);```
````

Comment: `initialCenter={{
            lat: lati,
            lng: long
        }}` and why `lng`? You've been using `lon` to define it previously...

Comment: lon is what I declared. lng is what google-map-react declares.